# SQL: First Occuerence and with value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have rarely use SQL, however for this task it may be the most suitable. I am looking to create a query that is able to detect the first occurrence of an incident for each subject.

**Record:**

```
------------------------------
personID | date    | incident
------------------------------
1         20150901      F1
2         20150101      B2
3         20150301      C3
1         20150901      B2
3         20150401      R5
2         20150401      C3
1         20150701      F1
```

Wanted Result:

```
------------------------------
personID | date    | incident
------------------------------
2         20150101      B2
3         20150301      C3
3         20150401      R5
2         20150401      C3
1         20150701      F1
1         20150901      B2
```

Simply: I am looking for the first (based on date) time the incident occurs for each personID, ignoring if the incident reoccurs.

Thanks

PS. Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I have. However, because I am looking for the first time an incident occurs per personID. A personID can have multiple different incidents occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MIN should work for this:

```
select personId,incident,MIN(convert(date,date)) as date
from [table]
group by personId,incident
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It does exactly what I need to. Is it possible to amend the query to then perform a PDATE/SET on a specific field that is only related to those that have been grouped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` function to get the desired result.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2d86/1)

```
select personid, date, incident
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by personid, incident order by date) as rn
from tablename
) x
where x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to amend the query to allow for an update?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH
    temp AS (
        SELECT  personID, date, incident,
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personID, incident ORDER BY date)
        FROM    my_table
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    temp
WHERE   rn = 1
```